# Meaning of 火冒三丈

Tags: translation, meaning, etymology

What is the meaning and literal translation of this phrase or idiom? I have not has a clear understand of this base on dictionary searches and web searches.

Example sentence would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From Pleco:

[image: 火冒三丈 - pleco]

Examples from [http://www.ichacha.net/m/火冒三丈.html](http://www.ichacha.net/m/%E7%81%AB%E5%86%92%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%88.html):

- > Babbitt raged, "i'm sick of it!"
  >
  > 巴比特**火冒三丈**：“烦死我了!”
- > You madden me when you talk of the diamond!
  >
  > 您一提起宝石，我就**火冒三丈**！
- > Mason was fairly beside himself with rage .
  >
  > 梅森**火冒三丈**，简直控制不住了。
- > His obstinacy drives me mad !
  >
  > 他顽固不化把我气得**火冒三丈**。
- > Her criticisms were enough to make anyone see red .
  >
  > 她那些批评任谁都得**火冒三丈**。

If these examples do not suffice, at least 20 more can be found at 百度翻译：[https://fanyi.baidu.com/#zh/en/火冒三丈](https://fanyi.baidu.com/#zh/en/%E7%81%AB%E5%86%92%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%88)

Comment: OP also asks for the literal translation. Can you provide that too?

Comment: Literal translation  -- "the fire boldly rose 30 feet" In this context 丈 does not mean husband, but a unit of measure. One 丈 = 10 feet, (or thereabouts in modern terms) If you want to say husband, it is 丈夫.

Comment: @WayneCheah interesting, makes sense

Comment: BTW, why are husbands called 丈夫? In the old days, people got married for many reasons, and private, emotional love was way down the scale as most marriages were arranged ones. Ability, wealth and a steady job were the qualities of the day. (as it is today, I suppose) So, an "ideal" husband was one who was one 丈 tall, (exaggerated of course), and a 夫, i.e. a man with a profession, a working man, a man who knows a craft; example, 农夫, farmer,  大夫, a doctor in the old days. So, an ideal husband, (then and now, I suppose), was one who was tall and had a good job.

Comment: @WayneCheah that’s very interesting! I agree with you, I think that this is often the case today, as it was in the past

Answer (score 0):

Try asking the [Great God Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%81%AB%E5%86%92%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%88/4472996?fr=aladdin), she who knoweth all:

火冒三丈，汉语成语，拼音是huǒ mào sān zhàng，意思是形容愤怒到极点。出自《筹安会六君子传》

意思是形容愤怒到极点
meaning is to describe angry in the extreme

Answer (score 0):

It means really angry.

指怒火冒出至三丈之高，形容极度生气、愤怒至极。

[Examples](https://dict.my-helper.com/cn/%E7%81%AB%E5%86%92%E4%B8%89%E4%B8%88/)